# Can I tell a recruiter I'm more interested in another position I applied for?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

In short, I applied for a Business Analyst position at a big tech company and have my third-round interviews coming up. However, they recently posted a PM position that I also applied to, and feel like my background and professional interests align more closely with this role.

Is it appropriate to tell the recruiter, that I'm already in contact with for the business analyst interviews, that I'm more interested in the PM position I applied for instead, and if I could receive an interview for that one instead?

Comment: Yes, of course. But if you still have some interest in the BA position, don't close that off.

Comment: @MichaelMcFarlane thank you! I am interested in the BA position too, so I gather I shouldn't tell the interviewer himself that I'm more interested for the PM. If I pass these upcoming BA interviews should I bring it up when the recruiter contacts me for next steps, or should I ask to have call (or just email?) the recruiter already and ask?

Comment: since this is turning into an actual answer, see below.

Comment: Welcome.  Thanks for your question, in the future, you may want to wait a bit before selecting the best answer.

Comment: @Old_Lamplighter is right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, be open with your recruiter, and sooner the better. In the worst case, your recruiter will end that line of inquiry. In the best case, your recruiter places you in a position that's a better fit for both you and the company.

The only question is "instead" vs "in addition". If you'd be happy in the BA position, tell the recruiter you'd prefer the PM position, but would like to keep pursuing the BA position as well.